# Object.merge creates AND in SQL query- what method creates OR?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

The following code, which uses a merge produces the SQL below. I've marked in bold the operator I want to change.

```
   Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self).merge(
    Micropost.direct_replies_to(self))
```

SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."reply_to" = 'example-1' **AND** (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
 WHERE follower_id = 2) AND user_id = 2) ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC

What method produces an OR operator between the two? ie:

SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."reply_to" = 'example-1' **OR** (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
 WHERE follower_id = 2) AND user_id = 2) ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC

Answer (score 0):

OR operator on one column's value, you can pass an array to Where clause and with ActiveRecord use IN(value1,value2):

for one column
`Micropost.where(:reply_to => ["value1", "value2"])`

for more column
`Micropost.where("reply_to = ? or follower_id = ?", 'example-1', 2)`

or try this

`Micropost.where("(reply_to = 'example-1') or (another_condition))`

Comment: You can also use `Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self) || Micropost.direct_replies_to(self)`